# WebAPI with MVC - should I use PUT to update a boolean on an object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I have a method like "setAsViewed" that takes an Id and just flips a boolean, but I'm not sure which of the four options here would be best.  My thinking is that I want to send as little data as possible, so one of the {id} options is best.  And since PUT usually corresponds to updates, I'm leaning towards the first.  What's the convention here?

**Options to flip a given object's boolean field (that I can think of):**

```
1. PUT /api/objects/setasviewed/1
2. PUT /api/object/setasviewed
3. POST /api/objects/setasviewed/1
4. POST /api/object/setasviewed
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quick Guideline for REST:

> **GET /api/objects** : List objects
>
> **GET /api/objects/1** : Get the object with id == 1
>
> **POST /api/objects** : Create a new object with posted data (full model)
>
> **PUT /api/objects/1** : Update object with id == 1 with posted data (full model)
>
> **PATCH /api/objects/1** : Update object with id == 1 with partial data (partial model)
>
> **POST /api/objects/1/someprocedure** : Run some procedure on object with id == 1

So in your scenario, it should be:

```
POST /api/objects/1/setasviewed
```

Or perhaps:

```
PATCH /api/objects/1
```

With posted data:

```
{ "viewed" : true }
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much.  I'm wondering - why pass in the field/value if all you really *need* to send across the wire is the Id?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you talking about my PATCH example? You need to post the data you want changed with a PATCH. In the `POST /api/objects/1/setasviewed` all you're doing is basically making a function call with no arguments. The logic to set `viewed` to `true` would be encapsulated in the action, in that scenario. You could potentially do something like `POST /api/objects/1/setviewedstatus` and then post something like `{ "viewed" : true }` or `{ "viewed : false }` with it, which would be like calling the function with a `viewed` argument.

Comment: I'm sorry - I was referring to your "with posted data" comment.  I mean why not just send { id : 1 }, much like a GET request for a particular object, except for instead of "return object[id]" in the controller, we're doing "flipProperty(object[id])"?

Comment: Because that violates a principle of REST. An object has a uniform resource location and everything that happens on that object should happen around its uniform resource locator.